Getting an error while foing DATE_ADD in DuckDB
DuckDB version: v0.10.2,
Python version: 3.11.4
When I am trying to use the DATE_ADD function it raises a ParserException.
To recreate the issue,
data = [['2020-01-01', 4], ['2020-01-02',5]]
p = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['cdate', 'days'])
print(p.info())
q = """
    SELECT DATE_ADD(CAST(p.cdate AS DATE), INTERVAL p.days DAY) pp
    FROM p 
"""
duckdb.sql(q).df()

which results in
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   cdate   2 non-null      object
 1   days    2 non-null      int64 
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 164.0+ bytes
None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserException                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[42], line 8
      3 print(p.info())
      4 q = """
      5     SELECT DATE_ADD(CAST(p.cdate AS DATE), INTERVAL p.days DAY) pp
      6     FROM p 
      7 """
----> 8 duckdb.sql(q).df()

ParserException: Parser Error: syntax error at or near "p"

If I change the line
SELECT DATE_ADD(CAST(p.cdate AS DATE), INTERVAL p.days DAY) pp

to
SELECT DATE_ADD(CAST(p.cdate AS DATE), INTERVAL 5 DAY) pp

it is working as expected. Tried an explicit casting of p.days to INTEGER, which also led to the same exception.

It seems parens are needed? INTERVAL (p.days) DAY

That works! But no clue on how.

The DuckDB parser only accepts integer and string constants here. To use an expression you need to put it in parentheses.
            | ConstInterval '(' a_expr ')' opt_interval
                {
                    $$ = makeIntervalNode($3, @3, $5);
                }
            | ConstInterval Iconst opt_interval
                {
                    $$ = makeIntervalNode($2, @2, $3);
                }
            | ConstInterval Sconst opt_interval
                {
                    $$ = makeIntervalNode($2, @2, $3);
                }

